# Can we update VBA code using a variable with Call()

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a sub routine to change all controls in a frame to either Enabled = True or False.

I have multiple frames that this should be applied to so I am trying to write it in a sub routine as follows. Where in the line UserForm1.frame1.Controls, the frame1 is a variable that can be assigned when the routine is called. ex  Call frame_enable(fraTypes), would update the code to UserForm1.fraTypes.Control when ran. Is this possible, I get the following error:

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

```
Sub frame_enable(ByVal frame1 As Object)

Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim frameName As String

    For Each ctl In UserForm1.frame1.Controls
        ctl.Enabled = Not ctl.Enalbed 'toggle Enabled property, use True/False if don't want to toggle
    
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

I have got something similar to work when updating background colors of textboxes. So when I use Call compare_greater_than(textbox2, textbox2) it runs with no errors.

```
Sub compare_greater_than(num1, num2)
'Circuit: num1 is operating, num2 is design
    If Not IsEmpty(num1.Value) And Not IsEmpty(num2.Value) Then
        If IsNumeric(num1.Value) And IsNumeric(num2.Value) Then
            If num1.Value > num2.Value Then
                MsgBox "Operating Greater Than Design!"
                num1.BackColor = Color.Red
            Else
                num1.BackColor = Color.Green
                num2.BackColor = Color.Green
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are passing `frame1` as an argument, you do not prefix it with the form again (that comes from the calling line). It should be something like `For Each ctl In frame1.Controls` - and you may want to try defining it as a `Control` instead of an `Object` and spelling `Enalbed` correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works as expected now. Much appreciated.

Comment: BTW using `Call` is optional. You can use `Call frame_enable(Frame1)` or simply `frame_enable Frame1`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to *@braX* , I just noticed that his comment was posted before mine. Essentially, we are highlighting the same point.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Call frame_enable(Me.Frame1)
    Call frame_enable(Me.Frame2)
End Sub

Sub frame_enable(ByVal oFrame As MSForms.Frame)
    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctl In oFrame.Controls
        ctl.Enabled = Not ctl.Enabled
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you and very much appreciated. This works as expected now.